# JMS. Send a simple Topic Message to a topic in ActiveMQ in WildFly 12 fails

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I want to publish a simple topic to a topic queue. Therefore im using ActivMQ-Extension in WildFly 12 (under subsystems). But I get following error:

```
CompletionListener/SendAcknowledgementHandler used with confirmationWindowSize=-1. Enable confirmationWindowSize to receive acks from server!
```

What is the meaning of this? 
Im using following Code:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Sender {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/jms/queue/bookstoreqeue")
    private Queue queue;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/jms/messagetopic")
    private Topic topic;


    public void send() throws JMSException {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");

        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(topic);

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("message");


        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
        consumer.setMessageListener(msg -> System.out.println("Received!"));


        while (true) {

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                messageProducer.send(message, new CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(Message message) {
                        System.out.println("complete!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onException(Message message, Exception exception) {
                        System.out.println(exception);
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that my MessageProducer is sending topics to the TopicQueue and that there is one Subscriber:

[image]

What could be here the problem?
By the way the same error appears on both : queue and topics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating confirmation-window-size in connection factory settings

Answer (score 0):

The `confirmationWindowSize` parameter is an Artemis CORE protocol specific setting and it must be configured properly to enable asynchronous send of acknowledgements. The window is specified in bytes, e.g.:

```
<your-protocol>://<your-host>:<your-port>?confirmationWindowSize=2048
```

Then, you just send messages as normal, and as messages reach the server, the server will send back an acknowledgement of the send asynchronously, and some time later you are informed at the client side by Apache ActiveMQ Artemis calling your handler's `sendAcknowledged(ClientMessage message)` method, passing in a reference to the message that was sent.

Also, Apache ActiveMQ Artemis clients can be configured to automatically reconnect or re-attach to the server in the event that a failure is detected in the connection between the client and the server. Keep in mind that, as clients send commands to their servers they store each sent command in an in-memory buffer. In the case that connection failure occurs and the client subsequently reattaches to the same server, as part of the reattachment protocol the server informs the client during reattachment with the id of the last command it successfully received from that client.

If the client has sent more commands than were received before failover it can replay any sent commands from its buffer so that the client and server can reconcile their states. The size of this buffer is configured by the `confirmationWindowSize` parameter, when the server has received `confirmationWindowSize` bytes of commands and processed them it will send back a command confirmation to the client, and the client can then free up space in the buffer.

Setting this parameter to `-1` disables any buffering and prevents any re-attachment from occurring, forcing reconnect instead. The default value for this parameter is `-1`. (Which means by default no auto re-attachment will occur)

Please see Apache ActiveMQ Artemis documentation for more details:

1. The "Asynchronous Send Acknowledgements" section of https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/send-guarantees.html
2. https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/client-reconnection.html
3. https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/perf-tools.html